# \b in python's re and exact word match

Tags: python, regex, string

How to make \b properly respect the word boundary? For example, understand the ' and not does partial match...

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "This is a test's test"
>>> p1 = r'\b' + 'test' + r'\b'
>>> re.findall(p1,str)
['test', 'test']
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean.  As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), "a word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character."  If you want to define words some other way then you can't use \b to do it.

Comment: for regexes a 'word' character is an ASCII letter, number or underscore: `A-Za-z0-9_`.  So a "word boundary" in a regex is the boundary between a "word character" and a non "word character", not an english word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can assure matching `test` that is not followed by `'`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is a test's test"
>>> re.findall(r"\btest\b(?!')", s)  # match `test` as long as it is not followed by "'"
['test']
```

BTW, do not use `str` as a variable name. It shadows built-in function/type `str`.

Comment: You should change your regex to the following `\btest(?!\S)` so that it does not partially match `test` in `testing`

Comment: @smac89, There's `\b` after `test`, so it will not match `testing`. For example `re.findall(r"\btest\b(?!')", "testing")` returns `[]`